# Is there a way to define an standard object's property's types and have them picked up by Typedoc?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, typedoc

I am creating a new class in *TypeScript* with an object that I use to monitor the status of certain things within the script. The object gets two levels deep. However, when I run *TypeDoc* over the object, it doesn't pick up the types that have been defined, instead assuming they are "any". I think I must have taken a non-standard approach to coding this object. How should I have set up this object in-line with preferred *TypeScript* syntax such that *TypeDoc* produces the expected documentation?

At first, I tried what I expected would work:

```
class ClassName {

    /**
    * A description of what this status is.
    */
    status: {
             /**
             * A description of what this property is.
             */
        pair: string[],
        db: {
            ready: boolean,
            interval: number
        }
    } = {
            pair: [], ...
    } ...
}
```

This didn't work. The `pair` property was not defined in the documentation produced. Next, I shifted the comments for *TypeDoc* into the default values I set for the object properties:

```
class ClassName {

    /**
    * A description of what this status is.
    */
    status: {
        pair: string[],
        db: {
            ready: boolean,
            interval: number
        }
    } = {
             /**
             * A description of what this property is.
             */
            pair: [], ...
    } ...
}
```

This worked in that *TypeDoc* would recognise the comments as referring to the following object, but would define it as "any". At this point, I figured I wasn't following the standard way of defining objects in *TypeScript* because I couldn't find an example online that matched this way of defining a class property.

I understand that documentation could be created using **Interfaces**. However, *TypeDoc* then separates each *Interface* into its own page. It makes the documentation very difficult to read. But this led me to a follow-up question, is this the correct way to define *multi-level object class properties*?